# R - dplyr 0.4.1 : How to summarise by a column name in a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a function that could ***group_by*** and ***summarise*** a data frame using the names of its columns. 
I'm working with dplyr version 0.4.1 (and I cannot update), so it looks like the solutions I've found on the other topics doesn't work...

Here is my example :

```
data <- data.frame(section=rep(c("A","B"),3), quantity=c(6:11))
#I need to get this result : 
RESULT = data %>% group_by(section) %>% summarise(total=sum(quantity))
```

I implemented this function, but I got an error :

```
# function : 
synthetize = function(x,column,measure){
  result = x %>% group_by(column) %>% summarise(total=sum(measure))
}
RESULT2=synthetize(data,column="section",measure="quantity")
RESULT2
```

I tried `eval`, `get`, but it looks like this doesn't help

Comment: What is the `R` version you have?

Comment: I'm currently working with R 3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

We can convert the string to symbol with `rlang::sym` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(tidyverse)
synthetize = function(x, column, measure){
     x %>% 
        group_by_at(column) %>%
        summarise(total=sum(!! rlang::sym(measure)))
   }

synthetize(data, column="section", measure="quantity")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  section total
#   <fct>   <int>
#1 A          24
#2 B          27
```

NOTE: Here we use the OP's same argument type

---

If we are using older version of `dplyr`, may be the following would help

```
library(lazyeval)
synthetize2 = function(x, column, measure){

  x %>% 
     group_by_(column) %>%
     summarise(total = interp(~ sum(v1), v1 = as.name(measure)))


synthetize2(data, column='section', measure='quantity')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot use tidyverse either... So I get an error message: `Error in function_list[[i]](value) : 
  impossible de trouver la fonction "group_by_at"`

Comment: Indeed, I'm using an older version of `dplyr`. Still, it looks like `interp()` doesn't solve the issue :  `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : Not a vector`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with `enquo`:

```
library(tidyverse)

synthetize = function(x,column,measure) {

  result = x %>% group_by(!! enquo(column)) %>% summarise(total := sum(!! enquo(measure)))

}
```

In this case, you wouldn't need to quote the variables:

```
RESULT2 = synthetize(data, column = section, measure = quantity)

RESULT2

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  section total
  <fct>   <int>
1 A          24
2 B          27
```

If you don't have access to newest `tidyverse`, try with `get`:

```
library(dplyr)

synthetize = function(x,column,measure) {

  result = x %>% group_by(get(column)) %>% summarise(total := sum(get(measure)))

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it doesn't work (due to 0.4.1 version of dplyr, I guess...) :  `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : objet 'section' introuvable`

Comment: Try with the method I've just added. In this case you need to quote the arguments.

Comment: Again, thanks! the `get` solution doesn't solve the problem... : `Error in get("section") : objet 'section' introuvable`

Comment: Hmm, that's probably then due to the previous version. Unfortunately I cannot downgrade and test easily.